# COUNTA not working as I expect in new Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, countif

I'm using the command `=COUNTA(I31:I)` to count all non-empty cells in the column. The cells in the column contain this line of code:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(D31), "X", "")
```

The result is that the cells are either an empty string (the line with add nothing `""`) or contain an `X`.

The problem now is that `COUNTA` counts all the cells after this procedure, empty or not. If I delete the long command line the cell is not counted and it works fine. So this long command line is adding something to the cell, so it appears *not-empty* even though it looks empty.

Any clues to what that is? My guess is that I should use some kind of `Null` operator instead of the `""` to add nothing to the cell.

**Note**: For some reason, this seems to work in a previous version of Google Spreadsheet I had.

As a *potential workaround*, I could replace `=COUNTA(I31:I)` by checking specifically for `x` with `=COUNTIF(I31:I;"X")`. But I'm still curious as to the problem with COUNTA.

If it turns out that my cells are not empty 'enough' for this command, how can I then make them completely empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### See Also: [Count rows with not empty value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43358591/1366033)

---

Unfortunately, this is *functions as designed* from Google.
<sup>Although I'm not sure why it's divergent from the way that [Excel calculates COUNTA](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-counta-to-count-nonblank-cells-HP010342340.aspx).</sup>

According to the [Google Spreadsheet Documentation on `COUNTA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991?hl=en):

> COUNTA counts all values in a dataset, including those which appear more than once and text values (**including zero-length strings** and whitespace).

Meaning that the only way to "make [the cells] completely empty" is to delete the entire contents, formula and all.  But fear not...

#### Some workarounds:

1. *Hypothetically*, you should be able to do this with [`=COUNTIF(A3:A8,"<>"&"")`](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/07/02/excel-countif-examples/), but Google spreadsheets doesn't support the ***not equal to*** operator in the [COUNTIF function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en) according to these forums: [1](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/zAT50FK9DDE), [2](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/FIOttjtaPYY), [3](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/u_XdYZGCcrE)
2. A workaround is to create a truthy or falsy array based on the condition and use SUMPRODUCT to count the truthy values like this:

   ```
    =SUMPRODUCT((A3:A8<>"")*1)
   ```
3. Another option you could pursue would be to [write a custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) and add it to Drive.
   It's actually pretty easy to do so.  Go to Tools > Script Editor and add the following script:

   ```js
    /**
     * Works like COUNTA except does not include null strings
     *
     * @param {cellRange} myArray The value or range to consider when counting.
     * @return Returns the a count of the number of values in a dataset.
     * @customfunction
     */
    function CountNotBlank(myArray) {
      var output = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) { 
        if (myArray[i] != "") {
          output += 1
        }
      }
      return output;
    }
   ```

   Then use like this:

   ```
    =CountNotBlank(I31:I)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I would try: =IF(ISNUMBER(D31), "X", iferror(1/0))

I am told that the iferror(1/0) returns nothing at all.