# Counting empty cells on a column, where other column have filled cells

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Right now I have two columns with data on Google Sheets.

My goal is to count the number of empty cells on column B, where column A has data.

[image]

In this example, the result should be the number 5

---

So far, I've got this:

```
=COUNTIFS(B3:B3000;"";A3:A3000;"")
```

But it returns 948, which is the total number of empty cells on both columns.

Thank you all

Comment: Because I thought it could be something, "Excel people" would be familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming nothing else in the columns:

```
=COUNTA(A:A)-COUNTA(B:B)
```

otherwise you can use `COUNTIFS` like so:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<>", B:B, "=")
```

According to [google docs count cells that contain any text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519073/google-docs-count-cells-that-contain-any-text) you use the `criterion` string `"<>"` to indicate *not equal to blank*, and I just guessed (correctly according to empirical evidence) that the `criterion` for equal to blank would be `"="`.

Comment: Great! It worked! I was actually working with COUNTA right now. BUT it wasn't working yet. So your solution still came on time! Thank you for your great contribution.