# COUNTIF text that looks like a number in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have created a sample sheet at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tzykNfURTm5RG91fQ7oF6kX0tGdwT8koRz7DKQ8Dosg/edit#gid=0.

Column A is formatted as `Plain text`.

When considered numbers then `1.1` and `1.10` are equal. But when considered text, they are not.

However, `COUNTIF` seems to consider them numbers even if it is formatted as a text.

[image]

Ultimately, I want to use this formula in a data validation to ensure the same ID is not added twice. As such, I don't think I can use `ARRAYFORMULA`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count cells that contain any text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519073/count-cells-that-contain-any-text)

Comment: @MrShane No. I'm not asking to count any text. I am trying to COUNTIF.

Comment: yes i know it is COUNTIF, i gave formula that does that but you dont like the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append apostrophe `"'"` before the cell value in the 2nd parameter of `=COUNTIF()`. The apostrophe indicates that the cell is formatted to text and force functions to recognize it as a text only.

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A, "'"&A2)
```

Example:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

As already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70602903/14678267

If you are certain that the values that look like numbers are text, or if you want to check if any that look like numbers are text, then you can use `COUNTIF` formula like this:

```
=COUNTIF(A18:A,"?*")
```

[image]

Comment: I am not looking to count cells that contain ANY text. I am looking to COUNTIF a range where cell value is equal to a string when the range contains text that looks like a number.

Comment: the formula i provided counts all the cells that have numbers, but are formatted as text, that is why it is COUNTIF, otherwise it would not work, but it does, yet you marked this answer down. maybe there is misunderstanding with your explanation.

Comment: I want to count how many times `value` is in a column when both `value` and column have text that looks like numbers. Yours only counts the # of values in column. I want to count the number of values in column that match `value.